Reliability Issues Creating Video from Image
I have an array of UIImage I loop through to create individual AVURLAsset videos. To create, I followed this post.
My issue is that there are times when all the images successfully convert, and there are other times when the images fail to convert to video.
In adding breakpoints, the reason is because AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor .pixelBufferPool is nil despite having started the AVAssetWriter and ensuring the outputURL available to write to.
Any thoughts would be appreciated, code appended below.
func convert() {
        
var completionCounter = 0

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    
    let videoProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videoProcessingQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
    
    videoProcessingQueue.async {
        for image in images {
            
            let settings = RenderSettings()
            let imageAnimator = ImageAnimator(renderSettings: settings)
            imageAnimator.image = image
            
            imageAnimator.render { asset in
                
                completionCounter += 1
                
                if completionCounter == images.count {
                    print("All images converted to video")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class ImageAnimator {

static let kTimescale: Int32 = 600

let settings: RenderSettings
let videoWriter: VideoWriter
var image: UIImage!
        
class func removeFileAtURL(fileURL: URL) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //
    }
}

init(renderSettings: RenderSettings) {
    settings = renderSettings
    videoWriter = VideoWriter(renderSettings: settings)
}

func render(completion: ((AVURLAsset)->Void)?) {
    
    ImageAnimator.removeFileAtURL(fileURL: settings.outputURL)
    
    videoWriter.start {
        
        self.videoWriter.render(appendPixelBuffers: self.appendPixelBuffers) { asset in
            completion?(asset)
        }
    }
}

func appendPixelBuffers(writer: VideoWriter) -> Bool {
    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(CGFloat(ImageAnimator.kTimescale) / settings.fps), timescale: ImageAnimator.kTimescale)
    let totalFrames = Int(settings.fps * settings.duration)

    for frameNum in 0..<totalFrames {
        if writer.isReadyForData == false {
            return false
        }

        autoreleasepool {
            let presentationTime = CMTimeMultiply(frameDuration, multiplier: Int32(frameNum))
            let success = videoWriter.addImage(image: image, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
            if success == false {
                print("addImage() failed")
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
}

struct RenderSettings {

var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)
var duration: CGFloat = 1.0
var fps: CGFloat = 30   // frames per second
var avCodecKey = AVVideoCodecType.h264

var videoFilename: String = UUID().uuidString
var videoFilenameExt = "mp4"
var outputURL: URL {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let tmpDirURL = try? fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true) {
        return tmpDirURL.appendingPathComponent(videoFilename).appendingPathExtension(videoFilenameExt)
    }
    fatalError("URLForDirectory() failed")
}
}

class VideoWriter {

let renderSettings: RenderSettings

var videoWriter: AVAssetWriter!
var videoWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
var pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor!

var isReadyForData: Bool {
    return videoWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData ?? false
}

class func pixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool, size: CGSize) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        
    var pixelBufferOut: CVPixelBuffer?
        
    let status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBufferOut)
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        fatalError("CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer() failed with status \(status)")
    }
        
    guard let pixelBuffer = pixelBufferOut else {
        print("pixel buffer out is nil")
        return nil
    }
        
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        
    guard let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer) else {
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        return nil
    }
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    guard let context = CGContext(data: data,
                                  width: Int(size.width),
                                  height: Int(size.height),
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
                                  space: rgbColorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue) else {
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        print("pixel buffer out is nil")
        return nil
    }
        
    context.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        
    let horizontalRatio = size.width / image.size.width
    let verticalRatio = size.height / image.size.height
    let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
        
    let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width * aspectRatio, height: image.size.height * aspectRatio)
        
    let x = newSize.width < size.width ? (size.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
    let y = newSize.height < size.height ? (size.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
        
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        
    return pixelBuffer
}

init(renderSettings: RenderSettings) {
    self.renderSettings = renderSettings
}

func start(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Start method entered")

    let avOutputSettings: [String: Any] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: renderSettings.avCodecKey,
        AVVideoWidthKey: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.size.width)),
        AVVideoHeightKey: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.size.height))
    ]
    
    print("AVOutputSettings created")
    
    func createPixelBufferAdaptor() {
        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.size.width)),
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(renderSettings.size.height)),
            kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility as String: true // Add compatibility option
        ]
        pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
                                                                  sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)
        print("PixelBufferAdaptor created with pool: \(String(describing: pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool))")
    }
    
    func createAssetWriter(outputURL: URL) -> AVAssetWriter {
        guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: .mp4) else {
            fatalError("AVAssetWriter() failed")
        }
        print("AssetWriter created")

        guard assetWriter.canApply(outputSettings: avOutputSettings, forMediaType: .video) else {
            fatalError("canApplyOutputSettings() failed")
        }
        print("canApplyOutputSettings passed")
        
        return assetWriter
    }
    
    videoWriter = createAssetWriter(outputURL: renderSettings.outputURL)
    videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: avOutputSettings)
    
    if videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
        videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
        print("VideoWriterInput added")
    } else {
        fatalError("canAddInput() returned false")
    }
    
    createPixelBufferAdaptor()
    
    guard videoWriter.startWriting() else {
        print("Failed to start writing")
        return
    }
    
    print("VideoWriter started writing")

    videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)
    print("Session started")

    precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil, "PixelBufferPool is nil")
    completion()
}


func render(appendPixelBuffers: ((VideoWriter) -> Bool)?, completion: ((AVURLAsset) -> Void)?) {
    
    precondition(videoWriter != nil, "Call start() to initialize the writer")
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "mediaInputQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    
    videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: queue) {
        let isFinished = appendPixelBuffers?(self) ?? false
        if isFinished {
            self.videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            self.videoWriter.finishWriting {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: self.videoWriter.outputURL)
                    completion?(asset)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // The closure will be called again when the writer is ready.
        }
    }
}

func addImage(image: UIImage, withPresentationTime presentationTime: CMTime) -> Bool {
    
    guard let pixelBufferPool = pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool else {
        print("Pixel buffer pool is nil")
        return false
    }
    
    if let pixelBuffer = VideoWriter.pixelBufferFromImage(image: image, pixelBufferPool: pixelBufferPool, size: renderSettings.size), pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime) {
        return true
    } else {
        print("Failed to append pixel buffer")
        return false
    }
}
}

